# In IPV6, what should I do if the last 2 boxes only contain 3 characters?

Tags: dns, ipv6, router, ip-address

I'm setting up a new router which actually allows me to change both my IPV4 and IPV6 DNS Servers.  I'm adding [AdGuard DNS](https://adguard.com/en/adguard-dns/overview.html#instruction) for both and setting up the IPV4 was no problem at all since I've done it a few times in the past when needed.  However when I began adding the in for the IPV6 one I found that the last two boxes only contain 3 characters, not 4 like everything else.  In other words, here is what AdGuard's IPV6 DNS servers look like:

```
2a00:5a60::ad1:0ff
2a00:5a60::ad2:0ff
```

Now, I know that "::" is the same as "0000" for as many boxes until a new address number is added.  So for this, there are 2 boxes with the digits `2a00` and `5a60` for both primary and secondary servers.  These are followed by 4 boxes of `0000`.  But here comes the part I'm not sure I understand, the last two boxes contain `ad1:0ff` and `ad2/0ff`.

When entering in these IPV6 numbers, should I add an extra "0" to the from of the boxes with only 3 digits?  Should I leave them as they are, with only 3 digits instead of 4?  For the time-being I'm just going to tell my router to use my ISP's IPV6, but I definitely want to switch to AdGuard's since it blocks so many different annoyances.

Any help you can offer would be awesome!  Thanks a lot!

Comment: strange, leading `0` are optional, you IP can be write as  `2a00:5a60::ad1:ff`  (or  `2a00:5a60::0ad1:00ff` ) and `2a00:5a60::ad2/ff` doesn't look like a valid IPV6.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite follow you.  Are you saying I should disable the IPV6 because it looks invalid?

Comment: no, simply use `2a00:5a60::ad1:ff` (as seen in "non filtering" section of link you provide)

Comment: All this because AdGuard wanted to appear "leet" and have its DNS server IPv6 addresses in its doco read "ad off" and "bad off" in their last two words.

Comment: `.../123` would be CIDR notation for an address block, but the number there is decimal, so `/ff` doesn't mean anything (and in any case, an IPv6 address only has 128 bits, so even `/256` doesn't mean anything)

Answer (score 4):

According to [RFC 4291 Section 2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291#section-2.2) you can shorten any address that has zeros in the following ways:

- An entire string of zeros can be removed, you can only do this once.

  ```
    1234:5678:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:abcd  
    1234:5678::abcd
  ```
- 4 zeros can be removed, leaving only a single zero.

  ```
    1234:0000:5678:0000:abcd:0000:ef00:0000  
    1234:0:5678:0:abcd:0:ef00:0
  ```
- Leading zeros can be removed

  ```
    1234:000a:000b:000c:000d:000e:000f:0000  
    1234:a:b:c:d:e:f:0
  ```

A key quote from the RFC:

> Note that it is not necessary to write the leading zeros in an individual field, but there must be at least one numeral in every field.

So technically, you can omit up to any leading zero as long as there is at least 1 hexadecimal numeral in every field except for the exception regarding entire fields with only zeros (they can be shortened to `::`). So AdGuard can omit 1 zero or both zeros. Either are valid shortenings. As user JdeBP points out, AdGuard used a kind of [Domain Hack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_hack) "to appear 'leet' and have its DNS server IPv6 addresses in its doco read 'ad off' and 'bad off' in their last two words".

So in your case the full address is:

```
2a00:5a60:0000:0000:0000:0000:0ad1:00ff
2a00:5a60:0000:0000:0000:0000:0ad2:00ff
```

And can alternatively be shortened to:

```
2a00:5a60::ad1:ff
2a00:5a60::ad2:ff
```

However, as previously mentioned, they wanted it to show up as "ad off".

Comment: Many thanks!  Your explanation was great and the full addresses you provided were the cherry on top!

Comment: "...you need to remove all leading zeros." -- did you mean "should remove"? I mean, doesn't that linked AdGuard page serve as proof that you don't _have_ to remove all leading zeroes.

Comment: @ilkkachu I can make that edit. It just feels like bad form, however. It is better to follow the guidelines for shortening IPV6 addresses than not. Clearly it confused at least one person.

Comment: What "guidelines" are you referring to? Can you add a link? I don't think there are any constraints on which leading zeros are you allowed to omit.

Comment: @TooTea added the relevant RFC to the post. There are no "constraints" other than it makes sense to shorten the address as much as is allowed by the RFC if you are going to shorten it at all. Adguard is effectively doing a domain hack with their IPV6 address to have it be "ad off".